# Runing total - found the date the running total is X

Tags: sql, t-sql, window-functions

I need to found which players (CID) have a deposit total of 100 or more and the exact date they reached that amount.

the Deposits table :

```
CID        DATE        Deposit_Amount
===        =====       ===============
1234       1/6          20
2345       5/6          30
1234       16/6         1
1234       18/6         50
3456       19/6         18
1234       25/6         150 
2345       31/7         50
2345       1/8          18
3456       1/9          50 
1234       5/9          23
3456       5/10         33
```

The answer should be :

```
CID    Date
===    ====
1234   25/6
3456   5/10
```

I tried to use the following query, but I don't know how to find the exact date that the user reached 100 and more

```
SELECT [CID]
      ,[Date]
      ,deposit 
      ,SUM([Deposit])OVER(PARTITION BY CID ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Total_deposit
  FROM [ISC_RAS_CD_MAXDB].[dbo].[Deposits]
```

any suggest ? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
select cid, min(date)
from (
    select t.*, sum(deposit_amount) over(partition by cid order by date) sum_deposit_amount
    from mytable t
) t
where sum_deposit_amount >= 100
group by cid
```

The subquery does a window sum of the `deposit_amount` per `cid` over the `date`; then the outer query aggregates by `cid`, and selects the minimum where the window sum is equal or above to `100`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without aggregation -- assuming the values are always positive:

```
select cid, date
from (select t.*,
             sum(deposit_amount) over(partition by cid order by date) sum_deposit_amount
      from mytable t
     ) t
where sum_deposit_amount >= 100 and
      sum_deposit_amount - deposit_amount < 100;
```

This should be more efficient than an outer aggregation.  Plus, you can bring back more columns from the row that first passes the value.